Binding data inside a DataGrid inside a DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate / C# WPF
I'm learning C# and WPF for a personal project that I'll use for my job.
I'm trying to create a DataGrid inside another DataGrid. Specifically, I want my first SQL query to display some data, and when I click on a row, it expands to show additional rows inside.
I've tried multiple solutions and searched extensively, but I can't find a way to get it done. The problem is that the second DataGrid inside my rows does not display my items, even though I can find them in variables when I start my app and use debugging points.
I'm quite new to programming, so I apologize if my explanation isn't very clear.
You can see some of my code below. If you need more, please let me know!
Feel free to ask for further assistance or provide additional details about your code!
XAML :
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="ArticlesDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Article Id" Binding="{Binding ArticleId}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom Usage" Binding="{Binding NomUsage}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom Technique" Binding="{Binding NomTechnique}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom Supplementaire" Binding="{Binding NomSupplementaire}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Photo URL" Binding="{Binding PhotoUrl}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Catégorie" Binding="{Binding Categorie.Nom}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tags" Binding="{Binding Tags}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid x:Name="LigneArticleDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding LigneArticle}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ligne Article ID" Binding="{Binding LigneArticleId}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial Number" Binding="{Binding SerialNumber}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Emplacement" Binding="{Binding Emplacement.Nom}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Emplacement Stock" Binding="{Binding Emplacement.EmplacementStock}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>

XAML CS :
private void LoadArticles()
{
    var articles = new List<Article>();
    var lignearticle = new List<LigneArticle>();
    using (var connection = Database.GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        var query = @"
    SELECT 
        a.article_id,
        a.description,
        a.nom_usage,
        a.nom_technique,
        a.nom_supplementaire,
        a.photo_url,
        c.nom AS categorie_nom,
        t.tag_id,
        t.nom AS tag_nom,
        la.ligne_article_id AS ligne_article_id,
        la.emplacement_id,
        la.serial_number AS serial_number,
        e.nom AS nom_emplacement,
        e.emplacement_stock AS emplacement_stock
    FROM 
        lignearticle la
    LEFT JOIN 
        articles a ON la.article_id = a.article_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        emplacements e ON la.emplacement_id = e.emplacement_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        categories c ON a.categorie_id = c.categorie_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        articletags ats ON a.article_id = ats.article_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        tags t ON ats.tag_id = t.tag_id
    WHERE
        la.ligne_article_id = (
            SELECT MIN(la2.ligne_article_id)
            FROM lignearticle la2
            WHERE la2.article_id = a.article_id);";

        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int articleId = reader.GetInt32("article_id");

            var article = articles.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ArticleId == articleId);
            if (article == null)
            {
                article = new Article
                {
                    ArticleId = articleId,
                    Description = reader.GetString("description"),
                    NomUsage = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("nom_usage")) ? null : reader.GetString("nom_usage"),
                    NomTechnique = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("nom_technique")) ? null : reader.GetString("nom_technique"),
                    NomSupplementaire = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("nom_supplementaire")) ? null : reader.GetString("nom_supplementaire"),
                    PhotoUrl = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("photo_url")) ? null : reader.GetString("photo_url"),
                    Categorie = new Categorie
                    {
                        Nom = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("categorie_nom")) ? null : reader.GetString("categorie_nom")
                    }
                };
                articles.Add(article);
            }

            using (var connectionlignearticle = Database.GetConnection())
            {
                connectionlignearticle.Open();
                var querylignearticle = @"
                SELECT 
                    la.ligne_article_id as ligne_article_id,
                    serial_number, 
                    la.article_id as article_id
                FROM 
                    lignearticle la
                LEFT JOIN 
                    articles a ON la.article_id = a.article_id
                WHERE 
                    la.article_id =" + articleId;

                var cmdlignearticle = new MySqlCommand(querylignearticle, connectionlignearticle);
                var readerlignearticle = cmdlignearticle.ExecuteReader();

                while (readerlignearticle.Read())
                {
                    int ligneArticleId = readerlignearticle.GetInt32("ligne_article_id");

                    var unelignearticle = lignearticle.FirstOrDefault(a => a.LigneArticleId == ligneArticleId);
                    if (unelignearticle == null)
                    {
                        unelignearticle = new LigneArticle
                        {
                            LigneArticleId = ligneArticleId,
                            SerialNumber = readerlignearticle.GetString("serial_number")
                        };
                        lignearticle.Add(unelignearticle);
                        article.LigneArticles.Add(unelignearticle);
                    }
                }
                //ArticlesDataGrid.ItemsSource = lignearticle;
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("tag_id")))
            {
                var articleTag = new ArticleTag
                {
                    ArticleId = articleId,
                    TagId = reader.GetInt32("tag_id"),
                    Tag = new Tag
                    {
                        TagId = reader.GetInt32("tag_id"),
                        Nom = reader.GetString("tag_nom")
                    }
                };
                article.ArticleTags.Add(articleTag);
            }
        }
    }
    ArticlesDataGrid.ItemsSource = articles;
}

Debugging
I can show my classes if needed but they are in multiple files.
I tried to update my classes and used different techniques to manipulate objects with either one big SQL request or multiple smaller ones, but it didn't change anything. I feel like my classes or my bindings are the problem.
EDIT :
So, I didn't really find a solution to my problem. I tried something else without using DataGrid to make sure I was doing things correctly.
Using an ItemsControl with an ItemsSource bound to my LigneArticle collection, it works as intended.
DISPLAY
XAML
Now, what I want is to be able to display items in a DataGrid. You might ask why I really need that, but it's simply because I want to be able to sort items while checking data with the application, and I don't know any other way without doing another SQL request with an ORDER BY or something similar.
I tried doing something like this, but it just displays nothing or multiple DataGrids.
DISPLAY
XAML
If anyone has an idea !

Please provide some more information about the ressources you have defined and how you trigger the event. It could be that you just run into a formatting issue as you say that you can see the correct data while debugging, mavbe the text is too big or some other formatting is required.

Which ressources you need ? Text shouldn't be too long. I've only few characters to display. The event is just triggered with the private void loadarticles, do I need anything else ?

For LigneArticleDataGrid try to use var lignearticle = new BindingList(); insted.

You're asking for a hierarchical view, when a DataGrid "popup" would do the job. You're "drilling down", and that's how the pattern usually works (popup). In that way, you can continue to "pop" (drill down) additional DataGrids without "stretching" the original grid beyond recognition.

I tried to create a "BindingList" but it says that it doesn't exist...
And yes, a popup or even another DataGrid that will load with an onclick event on the row would probably do the job, but I really need to be able to see everything in one DataGrid. It's going to be much better for our work and to have a clear vision of things.
